# Toggle boolean value with checkbox rails ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

I am new to rails and trying to change the value of a boolean via a checkbox and using jquery ajax,this is the part of a `projects/index.html.erb` that contains checkbox for `task` :

```
<div class="container">
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
  #some html code here
    <% project.tasks.each do |task| %>
        <div  class="row task">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-1 checkbox">
               <%= check_box_tag 'is_active', task.id , task.is_active, :class => "task-check" %>
            </div>
            #some another html code here
</div>
```

The `toggle.js.erb` file in `views/tasks` folder:

```
$(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
  if (this.checked){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"is_active": this.checked}
    });
  }
  else {
     alert("no");
  }
});
```

part of `tasks_controller.rb` with `toggle` method:

```
def toggle
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.toggle(:is_active)
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :tasks do
      member do
        post 'toggle'
      end
    end
```

But when I'm clicking on the checkbox nothing happens, I can't see any actions or requests in console